# Why is c.d.f. used in defining convergence in distribution.

Tags: convergence-divergence

The textbook of probability said:

A sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots$ converges in distribution to a random variable $X$, shown by $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$,  if
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{X_n}(x) = F_X(x),
$$
for all $x$ at which $F_X(x)$ is continuous.

---

However, my professor simply wrote it like the following: Convergence

1. in distribution: PDF of $X_n$ $\to$ PDF of $X$
2. in probability: ...
3. in mean-square: ...
4. with probability 1 (almost sure): ...

---

Convergence of CDF and that of PDF are same?

The reason why I ask this question is I've heard one day that
$$
E(X) = \int x~ dF_X(x)
$$
is true, but
$$
E(X) = \int xf_X(x)~dx
$$
is wrong.

Comment: Not every random variable has a pdf. But if it does, the the second equation is true

Comment: @user251257 You mean, the reason why the textbooks stick to using CDF instead of PDF is special case when the random variable does not have PDF, right??? Thank you

Comment: also, characterizing convergence in distribution by PDF is much more cumbersome than using CDF.